# Correct response for "Do you mind?"

Tags: responses

What is the proper response for "Do you mind?"

Comment: Well, do you mind? And do you want to be honest about it? How much regard do you have for the asker? Are you afraid of them? Do you love them? Was the asker being sarcastic, or were they sincere?

Comment: In what circumstances? Are you referring to asking permission to do something - "Do you mind if I...?" Rather than just say "No (I don't mind)", it's better to say something positive like "No - go ahead" or "That's fine by me" so as not to be misunderstood.

Comment: What is the question? Do you mind does not exist in a void.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously this depends on whether you do, in fact, mind.

If you don't, then:

> No, not at all.

If you do, then if you're in the UK you'll probably want something suitably apologetic:

> Sorry, I do actually.

Note that sometimes the question itself can be asked passive-aggressively - for instance if you're blocking the path, someone might say "Do you mind" to get you to move out of the way. In that case the response would be a simple apology as you move:

> Oh, sorry.